# How to organise dependent modules in a re-usable way?

Tags: nestjs

I currently have two modules:

- `Auth` which handles login and registration
- `User` which handles all user crud operations

`Auth` requires the `User` module to register and validate users. So currently, `Auth` imports the `User` module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [UserModule],
    components: [JwtStrategy, GithubStrategy, TokenService, LoginService],
    controllers: [AuthController],
})
```

However, as a result if I ever wanted to re-use these modules, I'd have to include both. Furthermore, if I moved the `User` module, I'd have to update all the references to it within the `Auth` module. Is there a better way to organise two dependent modules? Should they be combined?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your `UserModule` will be used everywhere, say in `OrdersModules`, `NotificationsModule`..., and you found yourself importing it and reimporting everywhere, then you should take a step to make this `Module` a `GlobalModule`, then it will be available everywhere in your project since it imported in `RootModule` i.e `ApplicationModule`

Just annotate your Module by `@Global`

[image: Example]

See also: [Modules | Nest Documentations](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules)